# Is a UK BRP card with "Leave to Enter" permit considered to be a residence visa for UK when applying for a UAE tourist visa?

Tags: visas, uk, dubai, uae, uk-residents

I have booked flights to Dubai, UAE on Emirates for tourism. Now I am trying to apply for pre-approved Visa On Arrival using https://www.dvpc.net/EK-OnlineVisa/.

I am an Indian national and I have an Indian passport. But I am living in United Kingdom for the last few years. I have a Biometric Residence Permit (BRP) card. My BRP card has "Permit Type" stated as "Leave to Enter".

On the DVPC online form at https://www.dvpc.net/Ek-OnlineVisa/ the form mentions the following:

> If one of the applicants do not have a valid US Visa / Residence Visa for UK or EU they need to apply separately as they are not eligible for a pre-approved Visa On Arrival. As per their itinerary the system will give them applicable visa category.

The form then asks for a "Visa Number".

Is my UK BRP cards with permit type "Leave to Enter" considered a residence visa for UK? If yes, should I enter my BRP card number as the visa number here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A BRP is a Biometric **Residence** Permit. It is only issued to UK residents. The word "Residence" is also prominently featured on the card. As such, it would be very hard to argue that a holder of one is not a UK resident.

The endorsement printed on a BRP varies, and can even be different for two people holding the same visa. "Leave to enter" simply means you have permission to enter the UK for some purpose, and does not imply that you are a resident of the UK. But the fact it is printed on a card that says **Residence Permit** certainly does.